# javascript toggle in jquery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which toggles an iframe on and off using just javascript.

But when i click the button, instead of just iframe disappearing, the button also disappears along with iframe.

While checking in the firebug console, the CSS of the button also changes display parameter to 'none'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'enigma';
    iDiv.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:5px;display:inline");
    document.body.appendChild(iDiv);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://example.com/index.html" width="400" height="200" style="border:0"></iframe>';
    iDiv.appendChild(div);

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.setAttribute("style","display:inline;");
    div2.innerHTML = '<button id="button2">Show/Hide</button>';
    document.body.appendChild(div2);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#button2").css({"position": "fixed", "display": "inline", "bottom": "0", "right": "0"}).click(function(){
            $("div").toggle('show');
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Well you toggle all `div`s when you click the button, including the one containing the button.

Comment: You're toggling every `div`. Is your button a `div`? Please include the markup.

Comment: ahh...my bad...i got the what i am doing wrong. how would i best change this to toggle only iframe? should i add iframe id?

Comment: @hnvasa You'll probably want to specify an id, or class. Changing every element of a certain tag is rarely what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone! One more quick question...when i open the page, it opens the iframe by default. How do i set the default to hidden on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("div").toggle('show');` toggles *all* `<div>` elements.

Perhaps you want

```
$("iframe").toggle('slow');
```

Or be more specific and add an `id` to the element you are trying to control as per [Iluvatar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091916/1921385)

Comment: Hm, maybe they mean `slow`?

Comment: oh its a type. Its `slow`. Thanks! One more quick question...when i open the page, it opens the iframe by default. How do i set the default to hidden?

Comment: @hnvasa `$(div).hide();` after you've created the element should do it. Note the lack of speech marks in the jQuery selector as we're selecting the element you've defined as `var div` rather than all divs. Shows us why we should be careful about what names we give our variables.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the button, you run

```
$("div").toggle('show');
```

which toggles all of the `div`s in the page. This includes the one containing the button. You can add an id to the div you want to hide to make it work:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "to-toggle";
...
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button2").css({"position": "fixed", "display": "inline", "bottom": "0", "right": "0"}).click(function(){
        $("#to-toggle").toggle('show');
    });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific here...

```
$("div").toggle();
```

You are currently targeting every div tag.